# XCUITest/Appium load on the app on iOS during performance testing

Tags: ios, webdriver, appium, xcuitest, web-content

We're currently testing the iOS (12.2 and greater) hybrid application with a WKWebView engine in Cordova using Webdriver, appium, and tests written in Python.

So here is a question:
does anybody know if XCUITest (which is used by appium to reach to iOS device and operate the app) or appium itself creates additional load on WebContent process (which is currently a part of the application due to WKWebView usage) during the test?

Here are some details on the issue:

1. The WebContent process shows ~600mb on the app start during the manual testing. Memory consumption grows up to 850mb and 750mb on average during the test (about 3 hours spent on that).
2. In the meanwhile, the same Webcontent process shows ~600mb on the app start during the automation testing. Memory consumption grows up to 1Gb and 800mb on average during the test (about 1 hour spent on that) until finally, application crashes.

This process is actually tracked with XCode.

I'm new to iOS testing but maybe someone else had something similar.

Here the capabilities used sent to appium:

```
"autoWebview": True,
"clearSystemFiles": True,
"automationName": "Appium",
"platformName": iOS,
"platformVersion": 12.2,
"nativeWebScreenshot": True,
"newCommandTimeout": 1814400,
"autoAcceptAlerts": True,
"app": *****,
"orientation": "LANDSCAPE",
"fullReset": config.full_reset,
"xcodeOrgId": config.xcode_org_id, "xcodeSigningId": config.xcode_signing_id,
"automationName": "XCUITest", 
"wdaStartupRetries": 5, 
"startIWDP": True,
"webkitResponseTimeout": 90000, 
"shouldUseSingletonTestManager": False,
"resetOnSessionStartOnly": False, 
"devicePlatform": "iOS"
```